# What is linear measure and linearly measurable sets?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am studying Real Analysis from *Wheeden, Zygmund - Measure and Integral*.

At Chapter 7, 7.1 The Indefinite Integral, the authors mentioned about a linear measure and linear measurable sets without any prior definition.
I have looked up on *Rudin - Principles of Mathematical Analysis, Rudin - Real and Complex Analysis*, Google but there is none mentioning what is linear measure or linearly measurable sets.

[image: book]

Thank you..

Comment: Could you add the paragraph for more precision please?

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace added even though I don't have the permission to do so

Comment: I think they refer to the diagonal $D$ as a copy of an interval, which they equip with the standard 1 dimension Lebesgue measure and call it linear measure (referring to the line $D$ is) and measurable sets linearly measurable. It is not standard and is just a sensible name they came up with for this example.

Comment: @TheoDiamantakis that makes sense, thank you very much